# Update current id based on next id in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table t1

```
+-----+-------+------+
| id  |  tID  | cID  | 
+-----+-------+------+
| 1   | 1     | 0    |
| 2   | 1     | 1    |
| 3   | 1     | 4    |
| 4   | 1     | 2    |
| 1   | 2     | 3    |
| 2   | 2     | 2    |
+-----+-------*------*
```

I have deleted a record where tID is 1 and id is 3 and cID is 4,
now I want that sequence to get updated like record with id 4 gets sequence 3
below is the sample data.

```
+-----+-------+------+
| id  |  tID  | cID  | 
+-----+-------+------+
| 1   | 1     | 0    |
| 2   | 1     | 1    |
| 3   | 1     | 2    |
| 1   | 2     | 3    |
| 2   | 2     | 2    |
+-----+-------+------+
```

Can I get an updated statement for this problem? How can I achieve this in Postgres?

Comment: Are there other tables that have column(s) in this table as foreign keys?

Comment: No, this table does not have any foreign key

Comment: Do you want to update only the row with the next highest `id`, or all ids greater than the one deleted? What would happen if the first row was deleted?

Comment: I want to update all the next rows, for example , first row gets deleted then all the next ids must get updated like where id = 2 it will become 1, id = 3 will become 2 and so on for unique tID

Comment: So deleting the first row would require an update on the next 3 rows (those with the same `tID`), but would not update the last 2 rows because these have a different tID (2 in this case)?

Comment: yes!!  deleting the first row would require an update on the next 3 rows (those with the same tID)

Comment: Not sure if you're shouting or excited, but now we know what you require.

Comment: sorry!! you got that feeling I had no intentions for that I'm just being curious to know the solution

Comment: If {id, tID} is a candidate key, then cID is either dependent on it or redundant. *WHY* does the cID for tID=2 does *not* start at `0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know which record you just deleted you can update like this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET id = id - 1 where id > 3 and tID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off presuming that id is (or part of) the Primary Key, this is a very **very** bad idea. The Primary key really ought to be IMMUTABLE. But if you insist on perusing it then at least do delete and update in a single step. Create an SQL function that handles both: (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3166c2e06ec42f2c81c644a258af9df2))

```
create or replace  
function remove_from_table1(id_in integer, tid_in integer)
 returns void
language sql 
as $$
with bye_bye (id, tid) as
     ( delete  
         from table1 d 
        where d.id = id_in
          and d.tid = tid_in
       returning id, tid
     ) 
update table1 u
   set id = u.id - 1 
  from bye_bye 
 where u.tid = bye_bye.tid
   and u.id  > bye_byeid;
$$;
```

That way later development (developers) would not need to make two separate calls, to complete the task. Even further I would put the function into a protected schema. Revoke delete authority from all schema except the owner. Grant execute of the function as needed. That protects the table from forgetting to call the function and issuing a direct delete.